# Put a javafx button instance in a "movable" node

Tags: java, javafx

I have a Event Handler that has a view instance (a javafx `Scene`).

Here is the code of the scene :

```
public class GameMenuScene {

    private final Button btnArcade;
    private final Button btnTraining;
    private final Button btnReplay;

    private final VBox mainMenuBox;
    private Scene mainMenuScene;

    public GameMenuScene() {
        btnArcade = new Button("Arcade");
        btnTraining = new Button("Training");
        btnReplay = new Button("Replay");

        mainMenuBox = new VBox(4);
        mainMenuBox.getChildren().addAll(btnArcade, btnTraining, btnReplay);

        mainMenuScene = new Scene(mainMenuBox, 300, 300);
    }

    public Scene getGameMenuScene() {
        return mainMenuScene;
    }

    public VBox getGameMenuSortcut() {
        return mainMenuBox;
    }
```

In my Application class, I first call the `getGameMenuScene();` The `mainMenuScene` get displayed correctly.

the problem is when I call `getGameMenuSortcut();` from an other EventHandler, the menu looks empty, but in debug I can see that the buttons are in the VBox.
Why do they not appear in the the VBox when I use getGameMenuSortcut(); in an other view?

Here is a sample of the other Event Handler :

```
public class EV {
    private final Scene EVview;

    private GameMenuScene sc;
    private VBox menu;

    public EV() {
        menu.getChildren.add(new Label("Menu")); 
        EVview = new Scene(mainMenuBox, 300, 300);
        addMenu(); //This add a menu with the 3 buttons, but they do not get displayed.
    }

    public void addMenu() {
        menu.getChildren.add(sc.getGameMenuSortcut());
    }
}
```

Comment: The information you provide is incomplete. In case the answer isn't sufficient for you, please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You are adding mainMenuBox to different scenes.

Comment: Yes, that is want i want to do, or at least the buttons. They are in the 2 different scene, but in the second one they don't appear, is there a way to have the same VBox in 2 different scene or something like that in javafx?